# GREP on a list of Regex and include the capture groups as separate fields in the output

Tags: bash, grep

Say I have two files

**File_1**, which has a list of user_ids and url (data is tab separated)

**Sample of first 3 rows**

```
user_1       https://www.truecar.com/prices-new/honda/cr-v
user_2       https://www.truecar.com/prices-new/mazda/cx-5
user_3       https://www.edmunds.com/new-cars
```

**File_2**, which has a list of regular expressions with 3 capture groups.

**Sample of first 2 rows:**

```
(truecar\.com)\/prices-new\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+) 
(truecar\.com)\/comparison\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)
```

I want to output the content of file_1 and also append the respective capture groups when matched as 3 separate fields. The output would look something like this. For simplicity, assume that none of the capture groups are optional.

```
user_1       https://www.truecar.com/prices-new/honda/cr-v    truecar.com    honda    cr-v
user_2       https://www.truecar.com/prices-new/honda/cr-v    truecar.com    mazda    cx-5
```

How can I achieve this? My attempt so far

```
cat file_1 | egrep -f file_2
```

[**Regex Fiddle**](https://regex101.com/r/RpAPYv/1)

Comment: So use `sed` to edit a stream.

Comment: Is each line of File_1 to be matched against the regex situated on the first line of File_2?

Comment: @M.NejatAydin There are multiple regex patterns in file_2. I only included the first row as a sample.

Comment: I'd suggest updating the question to include an example of `File_2` with at least 2 rows/patterns; an answer based on an assumption of a single pattern (from `File_2`) is going to be a (relatively) easy answer versus one based on multiple patterns (from `File_2`); even better would be sample patterns that have a different number number of capture groups (assuming said scenario is possible in your env); the more complete the sample (that matches your real world issue) ... the greater the chances of getting a workable solution

Comment: if a `sed` based solution is acceptable ... and assuming the patterns (from `File_2`) can have a different number of capture groups ... perhaps you could build on Jonathan Leffler's comment, ie, place the entire `s/<search_pattern>/<replacement_pattern>/` commands in a file and just pass said file to `sed` with the `-f` option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sed`. You regex seems to be extended regex.

```
sed -E 's/(truecar\.com)\/prices-new\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)(.*)/& \1 \2 \3/'
```

> Is there a way I can pass the file containing all the regex to sed ?

You can generate a `sed` script from the content of file2. Generate it... with `sed`.

```
sed -E "$(sed 's/.*/s@&@\& \\1 \\2 \\3@/' file2)"
```

Comment: How would I handle multiple regex patterns in `sed`. Is there a way I can pass the file containing all the regex to `sed` ?

Comment: @PhilCoulson: You'd use multiple commands, either with `-e 'command1' -e 'command2'` or with a file containing the multiple commands `-f script.sed`.

Comment: Sorry, I am still a newbie. How does the replacement pattern  `& \1 \2 \3` work?

Comment: https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-3 https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-8 https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command

Answer (score 2):

`Grep` is not suitable to handle multiple capture groups. Would you please try a `bash` solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

pat=$(<File_2)

while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ $pat ]]; then
        printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n" "$line" "${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}"
    fi
done < File_1
```

Output:

```
user_1  https://www.truecar.com/prices-new/honda/cr-v   truecar.com     honda   cr-v
user_2  https://www.truecar.com/prices-new/mazda/cx-5   truecar.com     mazda   cx-5
```